# NP-hardness of an optimization problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, np-hardness, optimization

While studying a problem in algorithmic game theory I got interested
in the complexity of the following optimization question:

#### Problem

Given:

- ground set $U = [n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ given by $n$,
- $m$ rankings given as total orders $\langle S_i, \sigma_i \rangle$
  where $S_i \subseteq U$ ($1 \leq i \leq m$),
- weight vector for $U$ given by $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Goal:
find a subset $L \subseteq U$ maximizing the following sum:
$$r(L) = \sum_{i \in [m],\  S_i \cap L \neq \emptyset} w(t_i(L))$$
where $t_i(L)$ is the highest ranked item in $L\cap S_i$ according to
$\sigma_i$.

I suspect that the problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. In fact the problem
seems to be hard even when all the $S_i$'s are of size $2$. However I
haven't been able to prove this.

#### What I know

It easy to see that the following restrictions make the problem easy:

- all of the weights are uniform: selecting all of the elements is
  clearly optimal.
- all of the rankings are complete rankings over $U$: the best
  solution is obtained by taking the element with the maximal weight.
- the weights are just binary ($w \in \{0,1\}^n$), then selecting all
  of the $1$-weighing elements is optimal.

However I haven't been able to find a polynomial time algorithm for
the general case (for example using LP).
On the other hand proving the problem to be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard doesn't
look easy. The structure of the problem instances doesn't allow easy
encoding of other problems. (Note that the hardness of the problem
will come from using the same $L$ for all partial orders, however
using the same weight vector for all of them makes proving hardness
not straight forward). I have unsuccessfully tried reducing some
$\mathsf{NP}$-hard problems like Subset-Sum, NAND-Circuit-SAT, etc. to
the decision version of this problem (is there a subset such that
$r(L) \geq k$).

A matching IP can be constructed quiet easily for a given instance of
the problem, but I don't see any sufficient resemblance to any problem
that I know of.

#### Question

Do you know the complexity of this problem?
Are there any references studying the complexity of similar optimization problems?
How would you prove that this optimization problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard? (if it is indeed hard).

Comment: I think your solution is correct and if you use a similar trick for the clauses, you can even restrict every Si to 2 elements.

Answer (score 8):

Well, here's a possible solution:

The reduction will be from 3SAT.

**Input:** $m$ DNF clauses $(\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_m)$ over $n$ variables $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

**Reduction:**
Create a set of items composed of two items for every variable: $x_i, \overline x_i$, corresponding to a $True$ assignment to either the variable $x_i$ or its negation, plus one auxiliary item $t$.
Let the price of all items $\{x_i,\overline x_i\}_{i=1,…,n}$ be $1$, and the price of $t$ be $1.5$.

Create two sets of consumers:

**Set 1:** Validity rankings: this set of consumers will encode the validity constraints on the assignments to $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Namely, that exactly one out of every $\{x_i,\overline x_i\}$ is set to $True$ (i.e., taken by the algorithm).
For every $i=1,\ldots,n$ create four partial rankings:

$\sigma_{i1}: x_i\succ t\\
\sigma_{i2}: \overline x_i \succ t \\
\sigma_{i3}: x_i \succ \overline x_i \\
\sigma_{i4}: x_i \succ \overline x_i$

Taking $t$ can never hurt, so we assume that it's always chosen. If both $x_i$ and $\overline x_i$ are selected, we get a payoff $4$. If none of them is selected, we get a payoff of $3$. If one of them is chosen, we get a payoff of $4.5$.

**Set 2:** Clause rankings.
For each clause of the form $\varphi_j=\ell_{j1} \vee \ell_{i2} \vee \ell_{j3}$, we create a ranking: $\sigma_j: \ell_{j1} > \ell_{j2} > \ell_{j3}$. If $\varphi_j$ is satisfied, it means that at least one of the items corresponding to $\ell_{j1}, \ell_{j2}$, and $\ell_{j3}$ is selected, which gives an extra payoff of $1$ from ranking $\sigma_j$.

Now, the 3CNF formula is satisfiable if and only if there is a set of items that gives a payoff of $m+4.5n$.